# FirebaseFirestore not recognized by Flutter (Android Studio)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code, slightly adapted from the example in flutter documentation:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

CollectionReference items = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('item');

return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: items.doc(itemId).get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Something went wrong");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
      return data['out_of_stock_location_ids'];// ${data['last_name']}");
    }

    return Text("loading");
  },
);
```

}

The code "FirebaseFirestore" is giving an error as it's not recognized as part of library that I'm imported. The import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'; is grayed out, possibly inappropriately so. I can't find where on the internet I can find why this is occurring or what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `cloud_firestore: 0.14.0` version and above you need to use `FirebaseFirestore` & `doc()` then  if `cloud_firestore: 0.13.7+1` and below you need to use `Firestore` & `document()`.

The documentation you mentioned is **updated** and I believe you are using now the lower version of `cloud_firestore`. If you want to use the higher or latest version of `cloud_firestore` you must change the version of your firestore in `pubspec.yaml` then visit the [changelog of firestore in pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog) to see the every changes and update of firestore.

Comment: Let me know if you tried the new version and the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you probably didn't initialize firebase in your main method you had to use firebase core for initialization

import core to **main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the documentation is outdated. I had to change FirebaseFirestore to Firestore and doc to document. I'm not sure how people are supposed to know to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this website=>

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/install

Copy the terminal code => flutter pub add cloud_firestore

after paste over your terminal and hit enter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).